# Connecting Spartacus with Salesforce backend

Tags: spartacus-storefront

We have a requirement to trigger transactions in Salesforce from Spartacus Storefront using Custom API.

What is the best practice for this? Should this done using OCC API in SAP Commerce Core?

Answer (score 0):

If you have all data in UI, you can call Salesforce API directly from Spartacus (angular). Maybe the authentication problem if you did't use SSO. You can not save account information safely on UI side.